# Convert Jquery to phone app?

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova, phonegap

I'm trying to convert a simple .html file to a phone application. I used jquery in writing the .html file, which works perfectly on my browser, then I used PhoneGap to create the .apk file. When I tried to run the .apk file on ARC welder, I got something that looks more like a web page than an application and there was no style or anything. It was a plain page with the text only. Can you tell me what I'm missing here? Do I need to download the .js and .css file and include them with .html file when creating the .apk?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Home</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page">

<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <a data-icon="back" onclick="history.back()">Back</a>
</div><!-- /header ------------------->

<div data-role="content"><p>Hello</p></div>

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
 <h1 position="center">Footer</h1>
</div><!-- /footer ------------------->

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Included `jquery` twice !

Comment: check for the browser console errors. "../js/jquery.js" won't work, better use "js/jquery.js" and create the "js" folder in your "www" folder.

Comment: requests to "code.jquery.com" might also fail because there are not whitelisted. Check https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/